# Using plot() to create a point graph with continuous and categorical variables

Tags: r, plot, graph

I am trying to plot a continuous value on the y-axis and a categorical variable to represent 2 groups A and B on the x axis. Every time I try this, I get this error message:

**NAs introduced by coercionno non-missing arguments to min; returning Infno non-missing arguments to max; returning -InfError in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values**

What does this mean? How can I fix it? If I make the group variable a factor (as.factor(group)) I end up with two horizontal lines rather than points. I want points, not lines...

Thank you for the help!

Here is what the data frame looks like

[image]

Here is my code for plotting:

```
   plot(saveDT$group, saveDT$value, pch=19, ylim=c(0,100))
```

Here is what happens if I make the group variable a factor using this code:

```
   saveDT$group<-as.factor(saveDT$group)
   plot(saveDT$group, saveDT$value, pch=19, ylim=c(0,100))
```

[image]

I want something like this but I cannot figure out how to create it myself in R:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `ggplot2` fairly easily:

```
ggplot(saveDT, aes(x=group, y=value)) + geom_point()
```